# Find the value property of an object that is inside of a linked list, using recursive function

Tags: javascript, list, recursion, linked-list

This is a JavaScript practice exercise.

Suppose I have a linked list object as follow:

```
   var list = {value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: {value: 30, rest: null}}}
```

I need to write a recursive method to find the value of a certain sub-listed object.

For example, the method "nth":

```
   console.log(nth(list, 1));
```

Should return value 20.

This is easy to accomplish if I change it to an array first.

However, I cannot change it to an array, the method "nth" has to be recursive.

If my method has to eventually return the value property, how do I make it recursive to the next sub-list? Doesn't the method has to return the next linked list in order to get to the object I desire?

Here's a hint that the question gave:

> The recursive version of nth will, similarly, look at an ever smaller part of the “tail” of the list and at the same time count down the index until it reaches zero, at which point it can return the value property of the node it is looking at. To get the zeroeth element of a list, you simply take the value property of its head node. To get element N + 1, you take the Nth element of the list that’s in this list’s rest property.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? 
StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to 
[try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). 
Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a 
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
For further information, please see 
[how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
and take the 
[tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

think the key to solve this method recursively is to call the parent method until the input parameter become one

```
nth(list, index) {
    if(list == null) return -1;
    if(index == 0) return list.value;
    nth(list.rest, index-1);
}
```

Comment: so close, yet a fail :p `return nth(list.rest, index-1);`

Comment: When I did not add "return", my "list.value" returned "undefine" though console.log(list.value) before this return showed 20.  Any idea why will it cause the function to return undefined?

Comment: Never mind, I see now. It is because the last execution of the method will not return anything so ultimately the method "nth" will not return anything at all to the function caller. Thanks guys

Comment: This is very helpful, but I wonder if it is better to wait for the OP to post their own attempt? Presently they have not evidenced trying anything at all. While it is not against the rules to help a student cheat, it is perhaps not ideal for their learning journey - nothing can replace their trying and struggling for themselves.

Comment: @halfer hey buddy, I'm learning Javascript myself, I'm not in school. This is just my little side hobby. I'm not cheating.

Comment: @LirenDing: fair enough. Nevertheless, as per the feedback under the question, we encourage folks to try something in the first instance, rather than asking a question first. We don't have enough helpers to scale up to the number of people who would like to get ready-made code without needing to try anything for themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
var list = {value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: {value: 30, rest: null}}};

      var  i  = 0
    recurs = function(obj,x){

      if(x===i){
        return obj.value
      }else{
       i++;
        return recurs(obj.rest,x);
      }

    };
    console.log(recurs(list,1));

var list = {value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: {value: 30, rest: null}}};
```

or

```
recurs = function(obj,x,i = 0 ){

  if(x===i){
    return obj.value
  }else{
   i++;
    return recurs(obj.rest,x,i); 
  }

};
console.log(recurs(list,1));
```

Comment: Got it, thanks! yet there is a typo error. return recurs(obj.rest,i), not x

Comment: This is very helpful, but I wonder if it is better to wait for the OP to post their own attempt? Presently they have not evidenced trying anything at all. While it is not against the rules to help a student cheat, it is perhaps not ideal for their learning journey - nothing can replace their trying and struggling for themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you can do it

```
const listRef = ( i , xs ) =>
  xs === null
    ? undefined
    : i === 0
      ? xs.value
      : listRef ( i - 1 , xs.rest )

const myList =
  { value : 10
  , rest : { value: 20
           , rest : { value : 30
                    , rest : null
                    }
           }
  }

console.log ( listRef ( 0 , myList ) ) // 10
console.log ( listRef ( 1 , myList ) ) // 20
console.log ( listRef ( 2 , myList ) ) // 30
console.log ( listRef ( 3 , myList ) ) // undefined
```

But you have a decision to make here – what kind of result should you get when `listRef ( 0 , [ undefined ] )` is called? How does that differ from `listRef ( 0 , [] )`?

`listRef ( 0 , [] )` should probably have the same behavior as `head ( [] )` – but I'll leave that up to you

Comment: This is very helpful, but I wonder if it is better to wait for the OP to post their own attempt? Presently they have not evidenced trying anything at all. While it is not against the rules to help a student cheat, it is perhaps not ideal for their learning journey - nothing can replace their trying and struggling for themselves.

Comment: @halfer I think you are a bit crazy.

Comment: @LirenDing: it is probably true `:-)`. However, if you would like to offer some more specific feedback, I am happy to hear it.